# How to upgrade Tomcat 6 to Tomcat 7 on CentOS server

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat6

Please suggest me how I can upgrade Tomcat 6 to Tomcat 7 on CentOS server. I did R&D on google but didn't get proper steps to upgrade tomcat and founded solution related install tomcat not upgrade but my requirement is upgrade Tomcat 6 to Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 0):

One cannot *upgrade* from an older *major* Tomcat version to a newer *major* Tomcat version; in your case, from Tomcat 6 to Tomcat 7.

What you can do is, migrate from Tomcat 6 to Tomcat 7.

Please read the general [Migration Guide page](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration.html) and then take a look at the [Migrating from 6.0.x to 7.0.x](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-7.html) page.

Here is an article on [Migrating old tomcat instances](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat#Migrating_old_Tomcat_instances). And here is a [link](http://www.davidghedini.com/pg/entry/install_tomcat_7_on_centos) on how to install Tomcat 7 on CentOS.